# Can we make $(1/n)$ converge to any real $r$ w.r.t. a suitable metric ? and other related issues

Tags: group-theory, analysis, metric-spaces

For every $h \in \mathbb Z$ , I can construct a metric $d_h$ on $\mathbb R$

such that $\Big(\dfrac 1n \Big)$ converges to $h$ w.r.t. the metric $d_h$ , indeed I consider a function

$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $f(x)=x$ if $x \in \mathbb Z$ ; $f(x)=x+h$ if $x \notin \mathbb Z$ ; if $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x,y \in \mathbb Z$ then

$x=y$ ; if $x,y \notin \mathbb Z$ , then

$x=y$ if $x \in \mathbb Z , y \notin \mathbb Z$ , then $x=f(x)=f(y)=y+h \implies y=x-h \in \mathbb Z$ , contradiction !!

thus $f$ is injective , so $d_h(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ forms a metric and since $1/n \notin \mathbb Z , \forall n\ge2 $ , so

$d_h\Big(\dfrac 1n,h\Big)=|f(1/n)-f(h)|=|h+1/n-h|=1/n , \forall n \ge 2$ thus $(1/n) \to h$ ,

my question is : can we make $(1/n)$ converge to any real $r$ w.r.t. a suitable metric ?

what about any other sequence which converges to $0$ in usual metric of  $\mathbb R$ ?

( I think I can prove that if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$ converging to $0$ with usual metric in $\mathbb R$ and $(H,+)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb R , +)$ such that some tail of $(x_n)$ does not belong to $H$ , then for every $h \in H$ I can construct a metric $d_h$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $(x_n)$ converges to $h$ w.r.t. $d_h$ metric ; for the above case my $(x_n)$ is $(1/n)$ , $H$ is $\mathbb Z$ and $(1/n)$ is not in $\mathbb Z$ for every $n \ge 2$  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather simpler function which will allow you to force any zero-convergent sequence (which is eventually nonzero) to converge to $r$ is the two-element swap: $f(0)=r$, $f(r)=0$, and $f(x)=x$ for all $x\ne 0,r$. This is an injection (indeed a bijection), so $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ is a metric, and assuming $r\ne 0$ (otherwise it is trivial) there is some $n$ such that $0<|a_n|<|r|$ and hence $f(a_n)=a_n$. Then this sequence converges to $f(0)=r$.

Note that the condition that $a_n$ be eventually nonzero is necessary: if $a_n$ is eventually $0$ then it converges to $0$ regardless of the metric, because constant sequences always converge to their value. And if $a_n$ is zero infinitely often, then it cannot converge to anything other than zero (although it could diverge).

Rather more interesting is the task of making an *arbitrary* sequence $a_n$ converge to $r$. Unfortunately, it is not true: the sequence $0,1,0,1,\dots$ never converges any farther than $d(0,1)>0$ regardless of the metric. However, as long as $a_n$ is injective as a function from $\Bbb N$, it is true. We can generalize this even further to the case when $a_n$ and $r$ are elements of any set $X$, which we will equip with an appropriate metric. Let $Y=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{r\}$ and define $f:Y\to\Bbb R$ by $f(r)=0$ and $f(a_n)=\frac1n$ if $a_n\ne r$. Then setting $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ if $x,y\in Y$ and $d(x,y)={\rm if}(x=y,0,1)$ otherwise, we get a metric on $X$.

To see this, note that $d(x,y)\le1$ for any $x,y$ (since the range of $f$ is contained in $[0,1]$), so that the triangle inequality $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\ge d(x,z)$ is satisfied if any of $x,y,z$ is not in $Y$, and otherwise it follows from the triangle inequality on $\Bbb R$. Then $d(a_n,r)=\frac1n$ or $d(a_n,r)=0$, so $a_n$ converges to $r$.

Comment: $a_n$ 's should also be non -zero in order to conclude $f(a_n)=a_n$

Comment: @SaunDev Good catch, added it to the answer.